# HTML/CSS: Image/div is not appearing in Mozilla but is in IE?

Tags: html, css

Can't figure out why the image is not appearing Mozilla while just showing the div container in IE. Anyone know of any solutions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Featured</title>
</head> 
<body>
<!--#include virtual="/header.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="/alpha.html" -->
<div id="WhiteBody">
    <center>
        <p class="HeaderFont">FEATURED</p>
    </center>
    <div style=background-color:#D9BA26; height:480px; width:320px; >
        <img src="images/Magic Hat #9.jpg" style=width:100%;height:100%; />
    </div>
</div>
<!--#include virtual="/alpha.html" -->
<!--#include virtual="/footer.html" -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need quotes around your CSS properties

```
<div id="WhiteBody">
    <center>
        <p class="HeaderFont">FEATURED</p>
    </center>
    <div style="background-color:#D9BA26; height:480px; width:320px;" >
        <img src="images/Magic Hat #9.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and try to avoid using whitespaces and special chars in your images names - make it `Magic_Hat_9.jpg`