# HTML/CSS: Image not appearing in web browser, just empty div?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML/CSS: Image/div is not appearing in Mozilla but is in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868812/html-css-image-div-is-not-appearing-in-mozilla-but-is-in-ie)

I am using Dreamweaver and the image shows up fine in there but once I upload the page and image to the server all that shows is the empty div.

I've tried removing the '.jpq' and I've removed the white space from the image name but still no image shows when pulled up over the internet.

```
<div style="background-color:#D9BA26; height:480px; width:320px;" >
        <img src="images/Magic Hat #9.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;" />
</div>
```

Comment: (a) Are you 100% sure that the relative path "images/MagicHat#9.jpg" is the same on your local machine and your server? (b) Try removing the '#' sign from the file name. (c) You should check your browser's error console for any errors given regarding that image. (d) Does a broken image show up, or just nothing at all? Some additional details may help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good practice to use underscores or hyphens instead of spaces when it comes to URLs, also you cannot use hashes as these are reserved for anchors in a page. Basically, save the image name as something else that doesn't have spaces or hashes and you're good to go.

Answer (score 5):

Save the image name in the mentioned format on the server

```
Magic_Hat_9.jpg
```

Replace the html tag to

```
<img src="images/Magic_Hat_9.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt use hashtags, because they are reserved.

Try something like

```
 Magic-Hat-9.jpg
```

or if you really have to use spaces, use this.

```
 <img src="images/Magic%20Hat%209.jpg style="width:100%;height:100%;" />
```