# HTML not showing style on (local) browser

Tags: html, css

I have made an HTML file (code will be shown below for reference) using some images and style sheet (from local filesystem).

My Folders are as follows:

> *Main* (contains the StyleSheet *Style1.cs* and HTML file *Page1.html*)

Images are placed in folder *Main/pics*

The style is perfectly visible in Code Editor (VS 2010), but whenever I run the file on Mozilla or Edge, etc, its failing to show any image or even style. Here is screenshot of html in editor:

[image: HTML is fine in Editor]

Yes I have seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868812/html-css-image-div-is-not-appearing-in-mozilla-but-is-in-ie) but my problem is not fixing even though I tried it on both IE and Mozilla (Edge as well). (And I have followed the preventive measures as prescribed by the question above)

My code is pretty simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Style1.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="HeaderDiv" class="top-header-blue">
Header
</div>
<div id="CentreDiv" class="content-header-white">
Test
</div>
<div id="footerDiv" class="footer-centre">
CopyRights 2015 - 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be so valuable. Thanks

Comment: Where is `Style1.css` located in relation to `Page1.html`?

Comment: You mean its code? Do I post it here?

Comment: no he is saying where you have put your css file as might be path of css is not correct. Do one thing, try to inspect or resource and see css is coming or not.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I mean where is the file physically located? As it stands your reference to it will only work if it is in the same folder.

Comment: Its showing the correct styles on VS, so presumably file is correctly addressed; its placed in same folder as html file as I mentioned in start of question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have given the wrong path in style as / in before the Style1.css just replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style1.css" />
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually I had done the blunder of putting style sheet both in same folder and another folder. Steve's answer suddenly made me realize the error